# C++ deletes the spaces in text file after changes

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

Okay, I've encountered another problem with my simple program. My program gets the text file, reads it, then deletes the last symbol and outputs the new text file with the changes. It does everything as I want except that it does delete all spaces. Any solutions for that?
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char symbols[10000];
    ofstream outFile("outFile.out");
    ifstream inFile("inFile.in");

    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {   
        inFile >> symbols[i];
    }       

    for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)
    {   
        if(symbols[j]=='\0')
        {       
            symbols[j-1] ='\0';
            break;          
        }               
    }       

    if(outFile.is_open())
    {   
        for(int l=0;l<10000;l++)
        {       
            outFile << symbols[l];
        }               
    }       

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.
I mean if I give it a text with 
Hello world

it outputs Helloworl
the spaces magically disappear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
inFile.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
```

There is a manipulator too, if you include `iomanip`:

```
inFile >> std::noskipws;
```

Comment: It should be >> not << :) But it works really nice :) thank you

Comment: Yeah I got that wrong initially. I get that particular typo a lot. Stems from doing more stream output that input I guess :)

Answer (score 4):

The `>>` extraction operator, when used with a `char` type, reads the next *non-whitespace* character from the input file. So, this skips all whitespace in your input.

You can use the [`noskipws`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/) manipulator to turn off this feature, like this:

```
inFile >> noskipws >> symbols[i];
```

Alternately, you can avoid using the `>>` operator. You could use [`istream::read()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/) for example.

Comment: @sehe: I didn't see your answer until I was finished editing mine and reloaded the page. Stack Overflow doesn't show new answers in the normal edit-refine-post cycle anymore.

Comment: mmm ok - I'll trust you on that. Still coming up with the initial response of `fopen` / `fread` was almost worth my -1. I'll leave it at neutral for now - as fair competitors, with _near_-equal timing :)

Comment: @sehe: +1 for yours so it doesn't look lopsided. :)